# Am I thinking about $C^\infty$ rings correctly?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathscr{C}}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
Let $\C$ be $C^\infty$, that is a set with operations:
$$\Phi_f:\C^n\longrightarrow \C$$
for every smooth function $f$ such that if $g:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$, and $f_i:\R^m\rightarrow \R$ are smooth functions for $1\leq i\leq n$ then:
\begin{align}
\Phi_h(c_1,\dots,c_m)=\Phi_g(\Phi_{f_1}(c_1,\dots, c_m),\dots, \Phi_{f_n}(c_1,\dots, c_m))
\end{align}
where $h$ is the smooth function $h(x_1,\dots,x_m)=g(f_1(x_1,\dots, x_m),\dots, f_n(x_1,\dots, x_m))$. We also necessitate that $\C^0=\{\emptyset\}$, and that $\Phi_{\pi_i}(c_1,\dots,c_n)=c_i$, where $\pi_i:\R^n\rightarrow \R$ is the projection onto the $i$th coordinate.

Now I am trying to show that this every $C^\infty$ ring is a commutative $\R$-algebra, but I think I might not be thinking about the operations correctly. Let $\C$ be a $C^\infty$ ring, and let's workout one of the axioms. Define the unital element $1$ by $1=\Phi_1(\emptyset)\in \C$, where $1:\R^0\rightarrow \R$ is the constant map $\star\mapsto 1$. We define multiplication by $c_1\cdot c_2=\Phi_m(c_1,c_2)$, where $m$ is the smooth map $\R^2\rightarrow \R$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto x\cdot y$.

I want to show that $1\cdot c=c$ for all $c\in \C$. Well:
\begin{align}
1\cdot c=&\Phi_m(1,c)=\Phi_m(\Phi_1(\emptyset),c)
\end{align}
and note that $\pi_1:\R\rightarrow \R$ is the identity, so we can rewrite this as:
$$1\cdot c= \Phi_m(\Phi_{\pi_1}(\Phi_1(\emptyset)), \Phi_{\pi_1}(c))$$
We then note that:
$$m(\pi_1(1(\emptyset)),\pi_1(x))=m(\pi_1(1),\pi_1(x))=x=\pi_1(x)$$
so:
\begin{align}
1\cdot c=\Phi_{\pi_1}(c)=c
\end{align}
This feels fishy to me; in particular I am not sure  I can make the reduction from $\Phi_m(1,c)$ to $\Phi_{\pi_1}$ because even by passing to $\Phi_{\pi_1}$ we have that one argument comes from the $\C^0$, and the other comes from $\C^1$. This is however the only way I have been able to think about doing this so I'm not sure what to think here. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit to add:

Ok, so here's what I can prove. First let $h:\R\rightarrow \R$ be the constant map $x\mapsto 1$, then we have that for all $c_1,c_2\in \C$:
\begin{align}
  c_1\cdot \Phi_0(\emptyset)=\Phi_m(c_1,\Phi_0(\emptyset))=\Phi_m(\Phi_{\pi_1}(c_1,\Phi_0(\emptyset)),\Phi_{\pi_2}(c_1,\Phi_0(\emptyset))
\end{align}
Let $f_1(x_1)=\pi_1(x_1,0(\star))$, and $f_2(x_1)=\pi_2(x_1,0(\star))$, then we can rewrite this as:
$$c_1\cdot \Phi_h(c_2)=\Phi_m(\Phi_{f_1}(c_1),\Phi_{f_2}(c_1,))$$
If we set $g(x_1)=m(f_1(x_1),f_2(x_1))$, then we see that $g$ is the the projection $\pi_1(x_1,x_2)=x_1$, so it follows that:
$$c_1\cdot\Phi_0(\emptyset)=\Phi_g(c_1)=\Phi_{\pi_1}(c_1)=c_1$$
so $\Phi_0(\emptyset)=1$.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467017/am-i-thinking-about-c-infty-rings-correctly You should not post the same question at both sites simultaneously.

Comment: @MoisheKohan my bad, which one should I delete?

Comment: It is totally up to you.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ok I will delete the other one. Do you have any thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I did not check your arguments but I think your excessive formalism with the operations $\Phi$  is unnecessary and obscures the fact that the proof is actually quite trivial.

Comment: @MoisheKohan how is the proof quite trivial?

Comment: @MoisheKohan that presupposes the notion that $\mathscr C$ is actually some ring of functions though no?

Comment: when you talk about $C^\infty$ it include [non-analytic smooth functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) like [smooth bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)? or includes only power series?

Comment: @Joako $C^\infty$ rings need not be actual rings of smooth functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathscr{C}}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$

Basically, the main equation says that any relation between functions transfers to the $\Phi$s. For functions, composing the constant function 1, the identity, and the multiplication gives back the identity. This should translate to basically what we want.

So, let $f_1(x)=1, f_2(x)=x, g(x,y)=xy$. Then $h(x)=g(f_1(x), f_2(x))=1\cdot x=x= f_2(x)$.

Apply the main equation and get

$\Phi_h(c)=\Phi_g(\Phi_{f_1}(c), \Phi_{f_2}(c))$

Of course $\Phi_h=\Phi_{f_2}=Id:\mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{C}$, $\Phi_g(x,y)= \cdot: \mathscr{C}^2 \to \mathscr{C}$ (by "compatibility with projections" and by definition, respectively). Hence

$c=\Phi_{f_1}(c) \cdot c$.

It remains to show $\Phi_{f_1}: \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{C}$ sends every $c \in \mathscr{C}$ to $1_{\C} \in \C$ (as then the above equation would become $c= 1_{\C} \cdot c$, which is what we want)). But this is true because $f_1$ factors through the map to the point, i.e. again from an application of the main equation, as follows:

Forgetting the previous notation, let $f_1: {pt_{\R}} \to \R$ be given by $f_1(pt_{\R})=1$; let $g=Id:\R \to \R$. Then $h=g(f_1)$ is the map $h(x)=1$. Apply the main equation, to see $\Phi_h(c)=\Phi_g(\Phi_{f_1}(pt_{\C}))=Id(1)=1$ in $\C$. That's exactly what we wanted.

This is close to your first approach, but avoids use of "nested" main equation (converting "triple composition" of functions to triple compositions of $\Phi$s) by breaking it into two separate applications of the main equation itself (you can prove a general form of "composed main equation" and then use it, thus making your first approach rigorous). Your second approach is a bit heavy notationally, so I did not go through verifying it.